# How to use sympy to generate Taylor Series for sine of x

Tags: python, sympy, trigonometry, taylor-series

I am using Python's [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to create a Taylor series for `sin x`

Following is the Taylor series for sin(x). Reference [here](https://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf)

Then following is how I should write the python code to create the Taylor series expression

**Code:**

```
import sympy as sym
import math

x = sym.symbols('x')

# Technique 1: Compute the 5 first terms in a Taylor series for sin(x) around x = 0. 
T_sin5 = 1 - (x**3/math.factorial(3)) + (x**5/math.factorial(5)) - (x**7/math.factorial(7)) + (x**9/math.factorial(9))
print(T_sin5)

# Technique 2: Compute the 5 first terms in a Taylor series for sin(x) around x = 0 using sympy
T_sin5_2 = sym.sin(x).series(x, 0, 5).removeO()
print(T_sin5_2)
```

**Question:**
As you can see above, I have made `T_sin5` using hand written way whereas `T_sin5_2` is made using `sympy`. So, my question is: Is Technique 1 same as Technique 2? Are `T_sin5` and `T_sin5_2` the same.

`print(T_sin5)` and `print(T_sin5_2)` both seem to print half of the series like below:

> -x**3/6 + x

I was expecting both the prints to priint out the Talor series for first 5 terms which will be like below.

> 1 - x**3/6 + x**5/120 - x**7/5040 + x**9/362880

Why doesnt `print(T_sin5_2)` print out 5 terms of the Taylor series like above?

**Python version:**
My python version is 3.8.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `n` parameter of [`series`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/series.html#sympy.series.series.series) describes

> The number of terms up to which the series is to be expanded.

This includes terms that are zero (as it happens for every second term for `sin(x)`). I.e. `n-1` is the greatest power in the series, so for `series(x, 0, 5)` this happens to be `4` and for this power the coefficient is zero.

For your custom version though it should print the full series (this is the output I get):

```
>>> print(T_sin5)
x**9/362880 - x**7/5040 + x**5/120 - x**3/6 + 1
```

Comment: Ah yes. The custom version prints all the 5 terms I added. My question was a bit wrong there then. I will correct it.